# Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CallCollection')

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, undefined, whatsapp

I try to scan my QR to start the session, but it is showing the following error every time.

index.js

```
const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new LocalAuth(),
    puppeteer: {
      headless: true,
      args: [
          '--no-default-browser-check',
          '--disable-session-crashed-bubble',
          '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
          '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
          '--no-first-run',
      ],
      takeoverOnConflict: true,
  }
  });
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "qrcode": "^1.5.3",
    "qrcode-terminal": "^0.12.0",
    "whatsapp-web.js": "^1.21.0"
  }
```

the error is:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CallCollection')
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:9:66
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\Users\I836659\Documents\MRPBot\ChatPedicure\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (C:\Users\I836659\Documents\MRPBot\ChatPedicure\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
    at async Client.initialize (C:\Users\I836659\Documents\MRPBot\ChatPedicure\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\src\Client.js:278:9)
```

Answer (score 2):

1.21.0 is a broken release. As a workaround until a new stable major release is out, try updating to version [1.21.1-alpha.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatsapp-web.js/v/1.21.1-alpha.1), based on [a comment in whatsapp-web.js issue #2388](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/2388#issuecomment-1672163310).

If you're using npm:

```
npm i whatsapp-web.js@1.21.1-alpha.1
```

Related links:

- [Issue #2383](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/2383)
- [fix: CallCollection PR #2385](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/pull/2385)
- [Release v1.21.1-alpha.1 with PR #2385 fix](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/releases/tag/v1.21.1-alpha.1)